# MongoDBb C# driver equivalent to getFieldDotted in MongoDb C++ driver?

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I have used the MongoDB driver more or less in C++ only. But now I need it also in C#.

For one of my functionalities I use the function "getFieldDotted" of class BSONObj to get a BSONElement is a deeper tree of the BSONObj.

It seems that an equiqalent functionality does not exits in C# driver!? All tries to use an "dotted" element name result in an exception "KeyNotFoundException" even if the key exist.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I found out, there is no equivalent to the C++ driver "getFieldDotted" function.

The C# driver is able to use "array indices":

```
value=BsonDoc["Element"]["AnOtherElement"];
```

I used this. It is the best for my requirements accessing specific elements that are at fixed positions in the BSON object without looping or searching.